# Grub Rescue Error and no partition on second Drive (Windows 10 and Ubuntu)

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, grub2

I am using **Windows 10 with legacy BIOS** and decided to try to **dual boot** with Ubuntu 20.04. From what I had read I thought it was best to use a **second Harddrive** for Ubuntu, so my Windows installation couldnt be damaged. So, I downloaded the iso file and burned it to a disk. I installed the second drive and continued with the installation of Ubuntu.
**Everything went fine**, in the installation menu I picked the right Drive and the installation process went flawlessly.
Then it gave me an **error message**, but I can't remember what it said, I just clicked ignore (That was probably a huge mistake). After that it proceeded with the installation without errors. After restarting my PC, removing the installation disk and using the boot manager to boot into Ubuntu, it entered **Grub Rescue Mode.**

I tried

```
ls (fd0,msdos1)
```

,which is the drive I installed Ubuntu on, but I got an error message saying "Unknown Filesystem" with every possible Drive I checked.
Then I used

```
set
```

And it put out something like this:

```
(fd0)/root/grub
```

As you can see in the brackets, it only told me a Drive, but **no partition**.

I tried Windows system recovery, but it didn't work.

What can I do to fix this issue? I heard you can do something in Ubuntu live mode, but what exactly?

**EDIT:**
I typed

```
bootrec /fixmbr
```

into the command prompt and after a system recovery I was able to boot into Windows. I checked the drive with Ubuntu on it and it said "510MB free of 510MB", which is very weird, because the drive had ~200 GB. Sounds like something is weird with the partition again.

Comment: I think fd0 is your floppy drive? I doubt you installed there. Probably hd0, hd1 etc. Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair  Microsoft required vendors to install in UEFI boot mode to gpt partitioned drives since 2012, so is this a very old system? What brand/model?

Comment: I didn't use the boot repair on the live disk yet, however, here are the system informations: My CPU is the Intel Core i5 760 and the Mainboard is the ASRock H55M-LE. The BIOS Version is: American Megatrends Inc. P180, 20.10.2010.

Comment: It's a really old system and because of that we unfortunately cannot update the BIOS to a newer Version. I guess the Ubuntu version I installed is only supporting UEFI BIOS?

Comment: No, any Ubuntu works perfectly either in BIOS or UEFI. If UEFI then the mode in which it'll be installed - UEFI or Legacy (CSM/"BIOS") - depends on the firmware settings and how the installer is booted. If you made the installation media with Rufus then, using its default settings you need to choose one mode or the other, MBR/BIOS vs GPT/UEFI. So, the latter won't boot in a BIOS based and the former in a UEFI based system it depends. Software like Balena Etcher (and a few other for Windows) copy the ISO as is and by default it includes both bootloaders.

Comment: Yours is BIOS (c. 2010) and last update released is 1.80: https://www.asrock.com/MB/Intel/H55M-LE/index.asp#BIOS (Instant Flash doesn't need any OS - https://www.asrock.com/support/BIOSIG.asp?cat=BIOS)

Comment: Please let us see details with Boot Repair as commented above. As long as you have changed the boot in BIOS to the second drive, installed Ubuntu to, and set the bootloader (Grub) installation to the same drive, the system should boot automatically to the Grub menu. If you have accidentally set it to install in the other drive (Windows) it would work the same but the Windows bootloader would be replaced but otherwise work the same. So, at first glance, there may have been a problem with the bootloader installation, was that the error you ignored? If so, Boot Repair can help.

Comment: Here is the link to the Boot Repair log: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/dmHHcpbtWH/

Comment: It looks fine, nothing stands out except a non-Windows bootloader installed in sda, the drive with Windows. Make sure the first boot drive is sdb, reported as ~150GB, in BIOS. It should boot to the Grub menu, allowing to select Ubuntu or Windows.

Comment: I tried to boot from the Ubuntu Drive, but it still entered grub rescue mode. I can still access Windows by booting from the other drive. Is it possible that my Ubuntu Version (20.04) is too new for my BIOS Version?

Comment: Note: I booted Ubuntu from the Boot menu and didnt change the BIOS options, because I didnt want to break things. Would that change anything?

Comment: Note 2: I think I know where the issue is, I didnt create a partition on my drive, but installed ubuntu on the whole drive.

Comment: @pion If you "didn't create a partition on your drive, but installed Ubuntu on the whole drive" run Boot-Repair and let Boot-Repair create the missing boot partition automatically. It probably won't boot Ubuntu, but at least now you have a workable boot partition. Then reinstall Ubuntu and it will detect and configure the new boot partition automatically and you're done. This method was tested on this computer that I'm working on.